# wcf PerSession (Wshttpbinding) with Portable Class Library (PCL)

Tags: wcf, portable-class-library, wshttpbinding

seems that Portable Class Library does not support PerSession (Wshttpbinding) required for this.

Is there any work around for this?

i have xamarin forms application (server client) that  users can connect to their own database and get or update data. 
once the user provide his username and password some information must be stored to their sessions like database connection string and when data request from user then the appropriate connection string that is stored to his session will be used for that database and send the data back.

otherwise without persession  i have to pass on every function the connection string from the client.

how can i avoid this?  Portable Class Library does not support wshttpbinding and therefore i cannot use PerSession

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Too much Headache**

The obstacles are too much for anyone working with the following combination

- Xamarin Forms
- PCL (Portable Class Libray)
- WCF
- IClientMessageInspector

**The Problem:**

I was need to have a multi client application that each one can connect to his own database ( same schema all )

For this purpose i was looking to store some information at a session level like (Connection String,User Information) so when a method called to know from which database i will retreive the data .

**Problem # 1** ( took me 5 days to understand and realized)

- that Sessions cannot be worked with PCL ( **WCF PerSession**) why? Because PerSession Needs WsHttpBinding but PCL Does not support WsHttpBinding only BasicHttp

**Problem # 2** (took me 3 days to understand why is not working)

- Then i saw many posts here and there about implementing **IClientMessageInspector** (*see examples online how to implement IClientMessageInspector it's easy*) so every time a client request a call to send some extra info to the server together with the call in my case was the connectionString. Here i was getting an exception that

  NotImplementedException. Why? because of this BUG in MONO
  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40064

in simple words

*When creating a WCF client in a PCL (targetting .NET Core) you must use EndpointBehaviors and not Behaviors. This works fine in a Windows RT application, but Mono has not implemented this so produces NotImplementedException in Android and iOS.*

The answer is on the link above by another reply from someone else and i thank him for that .

In simple words

Instead of

```
    MyService.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors(New MyBehavior)
```

Use

```
    Dim prop = MyService.Endpoint.GetType.GetTypeInfo.GetDeclaredProperty("Behaviors")
    Dim obj = CType(prop.GetValue(MyService.Endpoint), KeyedCollection(Of Type, IEndpointBehavior))
    obj.Add(New Behavior)
```

and instead of

```
clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(New MyInspector)
```

Use

```
Public Sub ApplyClientBehavior(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, clientRuntime As ClientRuntime) Implements IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior
    Dim prop = clientRuntime.GetType.GetTypeInfo.GetDeclaredProperty("MessageInspectors")
    Dim obj = CType(prop.GetValue(clientRuntime), ICollection(Of IClientMessageInspector))
    obj.Add(New MyInspector)
End Sub
```

No changes needed to the configuration file

Hope this help someday someone.